How to get shared projects in GitLab via graphql?
I'm attempting to query all projects under a certain group, including projects that aren't direct children of that group (ie, shared projects). I'm trying to do the equivalent of GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/{groupId}/projects but in graphql. The REST documentation has the with_shared property for this endpoint, and its enabled by default. I'm trying to find the equivalent in graphql but i'm having no luck
here's a condensed version of the query I'm running:
query {
       group(fullPath: "{groupPath}") {
          requireTwoFactorAuthentication
          projects(includeSubgroups: true, first:100) {
             nodes {
               id
               name
               fullPath
            }
       }
   }
}

I can't seem to find anything in GitLab's documentation that tells me how to query all projects under a group, including shared projects
For anyone interested, you can stage it on your end by doing the following

Create a project under a group, let's call it "ProjectA" and "GroupA"
create another group with several direct projects, let's call this "GroupB"
invite "GroupB" into "ProjectA", under members, invite the group.
If you go to "GroupB", under shared groups "ProjectA" should appear.

Attempt to query "GroupB", all direct projects will appear but the shared project won't ("ProjectA").
If you attempt retrieving that data over REST, you'll get all projects, including shared projects by default. If anyone has any idea how to get this working on graphql, I'd appreciate any help you can send my way

running into same issue with shared_with_groups missing in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/index.html#group ;/
